# Асинхронный декоратор в классе

Tags: python, asyncio, декоратор

Как сделать асинхронный декоратор в классе?
Я попробовал реализовать, но возникает проблема, которую я не могу решить.

```
import asyncio
from functools import wraps

class sa(object):
    def a(self, fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        async def wrapper(*args):
            print(args)
            return await fun(*args)
        return wrapper

    @a
    async def b(self, text):
        print(text)
        return False


n = sa()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(n.b('hello'))
```

Comment: В python специально по человечески сделан traceback. Ошибка описана. Только переведите и исправьте. У меня к Вам вопрос: в чём проблема перевести и исправить?

Comment: TypeError: a () отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент: 'fun'. Вот перевод, но я не понимаю, где указать этот аргумент

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (ссылка `править` под вопросом). А точно нужно чтобы `a` был методом класса?

Comment: В Pycharm есть удобный поиск: `Ctrl+F`. Вставьте туда слово `fun` и он Вам подсветит где он ожидается и фигурирует. Дальше нужно лишь знать как работают функции и передача в них данных.

Comment: Ну это просто поиск. Он просто нашёл все fun

Comment: a является методом класса, т.к. он берет значения из класса по self, тут этого не реализовано, потому что это просто иллюстрация проблемы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно вынести функцию из класса, тогда не нужно будет передавать `self`:

```
import asyncio
from functools import wraps


def a(fun):
    @wraps(fun)
    async def wrapper(*args):
        print(args)
        return await fun(*args)

    return wrapper


class sa(object):
    @a
    async def b(self, text):
        print(text)
        return False


n = sa()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(n.b('hello'))
```

Вывело:

```
(<__main__.sa object at 0x000001BF26808DD8>, 'hello')
hello
```

---

**PS.**

Можно и внутри класса оставить, но это может привести к путанице:

```
class sa(object):
    def a(fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        async def wrapper(*args):
            print(args)
            return await fun(*args)

        return wrapper

    @a
    async def b(self, text):
        print(text)
        return False
```

---

**PPS.**

Еще можно так оформить декоратор, и вызывать его для других функций:

```
import asyncio
from functools import wraps

class sa(object):
    def a(self, fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        async def wrapper(*args):
            print(args)
            return await fun(*args)

        return wrapper

n = sa()

@n.a
async def b(text):
    print(text)
    return False

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(b('hello'))
```

Результат:

```
('hello',)
hello
```

Comment: Второй вариант работает, но есть одно но - нельзя обращаться к полям класса

Comment: @N.Maxim self доступен внутри wrapper, пример отдельным ответом

Answer (score 0):

```
class sa(object):
    def a(fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        async def wrapper(self, *args):
            print(self)
            print(args)
            return await fun(self, *args)

        return wrapper

    @a
    async def b(self, text):
        print(text)
        return False
```